# Python del not deleting

Tags: python, python-3.x, del

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.quantity = 1

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.quantity += other.quantity
        del other  # Not deleting.
        return self

    def __radd__(self, other):
        if other == 0:
            return self
        else:
            return self.__add__(other)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.quantity}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<A object: {self.quantity}>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = A()
    array = [a,b]
    print(sum(array))
    print(array)
```

## Result:

```
2
[<A object: 2>, <A object: 1>]
```

## Expected result:

```
2
[<A object: 2>]
```

The function is adding normally but the `del` is not deleting the other items in the list.

I try to use the `other` after use the `del other` and it prints an error. But its not deleting the item from the list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `del` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.  My guess is that you think it causes the value referenced by the name after `del` to be deleted.  What really happens is that the reference named after `del` is deleted from the current namespace.
If that reference is the last reference to the value, then eventually (possibly immediately, but possibly not for a *very* long time), the referenced value will be deleted.
Your `del other` only deletes the reference named `other`, which has no detectable effect.  It does not (and cannot) change the contents of the list passed in to `sum`.